# how to split this string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to split this string using jquery?

```
"[10.072721346470422,76.32974624633789][[10.075854059674523,76.32043361663818],[10.073650930297095,76.32888793945312],[10.074918540288232,76.33090496063231],[10.073862198974942,76.33137702941895],[10.071960775892242,76.33034706115723],[10.070819916662579,76.32674217224121]]"
```

**Answer**

First array element:

> [10.072721346470422,76.32974624633789]

Second array element:

> [[10.075854059674523,76.32043361663818],[10.073650930297095,76.32888793945312],[10.074918540288232,76.33090496063231],[10.073862198974942,76.33137702941895],
>   [10.071960775892242,76.33034706115723],[10.070819916662579,76.32674217224121]]

Comment: @RohanKumar consider whole input as string..

Comment: I think your answer is here http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/mS8R3/

Comment: Thank u for your valuable information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var s = "[10.072721346470422,76.32974624633789][[10.075854059674523,76.32043361663818],[10.073650930297095,76.32888793945312],[10.074918540288232,76.33090496063231],[10.073862198974942,76.33137702941895],[10.071960775892242,76.33034706115723],[10.070819916662579,76.32674217224121]]";
var arr = s.split('][');
arr[0] = arr[0] + ']';
arr[1] = "[" + arr[1];
```

If you want array, do this:

```
var firstArr=arr[0].replace(/[\[\]]/g,"").split(',');
var secondArr=arr[1].replace(/[\[\]]/g,"").split(',');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCNaK/